# Fill remaining cell based on which column is entered

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to do the following:

```
     D       E                           F
1    P       Q                           pf
2    100     =D2/F2*SIN(ACOS(F2))        =D2/SQRT((D2^2+E2^2))
3    200     =D3/F3*SIN(ACOS(F3))        =D3/SQRT((D3^2+E3^2))
4
5    P       Q                           pf
6    100     =D6/F6*SIN(ACOS(F6))        =D6/SQRT((D7^2+E6^2))
7    200     =D7/F7*SIN(ACOS(F7))        =D7/SQRT((D7^2+E7^2))
```

That is, if I enter a value in column F, the value in column E should automatically be filled in, and if I enter a value in column E, the value in column F should automatically be filled in.

But, I don't want to display `#DIV/0!`, before I enter the value.

Objective:

1. Check if column D contains a number.
2. Check if either column column
   E or F contains a number
3. Fill in the remaining column

Also, I will enter names in some of the rows, thus these must be disregarded. I know I can drag the equations down and achieve it that way, but then again, that will give me `#DIV/0!`.

Is there a clever way to do this? I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: You can use two UDFs, =E() and =F(). What is a sample of what you would enter in either E or F

Comment: Some positive number. Typically 67.3 in E, or 0.85 in F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open VBE (*Visual Basic Editor*) <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- Right-click in the *Project Explorer* and *Insert* a `Module`
- Paste the below code

*UDF functions*

```
Function E()

    Dim D As Range, F As Range
    Set D = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1): Set F = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
    
    If Len(D) = 0 Or Len(F) = 0 Then E = ""
    If Len(F) > 0 Then
        Dim result As Double
        result = Evaluate("=" & D & "/" & F & "*SIN(ACOS(" & F & "))")
        E = result
    End If
End Function

Function F()
    Dim D As Range, E As Range
    Set D = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2): Set E = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
    
    If Len(D) = 0 Or Len(E) = 0 Then F = ""
    If Len(E) > 0 Then
        Dim result As Double
        result = Evaluate("=" & D & "/SQRT((" & D & "^2+" & E & "^2))")
        F = result
    End If
End Function
```

- Go back to your spreadsheet and enter new formulas
- Cell `E2` is now `=E()` and cell `F2` is now `=F()` drag the formulas
  down

Ended up with
[image: result]

## Update:

To *automate* the insertion and calculation

In the `Project Explorer` » right-click `Sheet1` » `View Code`

Insert the below code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 5 Then
        FillF Target
    ElseIf Target.Column = 6 Then
        FillE Target
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: code for worksheet]

In the `Module1` replace the code you have with the one below

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillF(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim D As Range, E As Range, F As Range

    Set E = Target
    Set D = E.Offset(0, -1)
    Set F = E.Offset(0, 1)
    
    If Not IsError(E) Then
        If Len(E) = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Len(D) = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Len(D) > 0 And Len(F) = 0 Then
            F.Formula = "=" & D & "/SQRT((" & D & "^2+" & E & "^2))"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        F.ClearContents
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub FillE(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim D As Range, E As Range, F As Range
    
    Set F = Target
    Set E = F.Offset(0, -1)
    Set D = F.Offset(0, -2)
    
    If Not IsError(F) Then
        If Len(F) = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Len(D) = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Len(D) > 0 And Len(E) = 0 Then
            E.Formula = "=" & D & "/" & F & "*SIN(ACOS(" & F & "))"
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        E.ClearContents
    End If

End Sub
```

Now, Go to you spreadsheet and enter a number either in column E, or F the other formula should be calculated and the result should appear in the neighbouring cell.

Comment: Thanks! It's perfect but for one thing: I can't get it to work, I only get blank cells. That is, if I enter numbers in D and E/F, the remaining column is still empty (but has `E()` / `F()` in the function-field) :/ I'll try some more, it was obviously working for you...

Comment: do it in this order: enter `D as 200`, enter `E = 67.3`, enter `F as  =F()` see if that makes a difference. I think that everytime you update one of the numbers you will have to refresh the UDF by clicking the cell with the formula and hitting enter